# Extrema of $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=1+|x|$

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

Let $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=1+|x|$, find the extrema of $f$ in its domain.

I did it in this way: the extrema are reached in internal stationary points, in the points such that $f'$ doesn't exist and in the points on the boundary of $[-1,1]$.

It is $\text{Int}([-1,1])=(-1,1)$, and $f'$ exists for all $x\ne0$ since $|x|$ is not differentiable in $x=0$; so for $x\in(-1,1) \setminus \{0\}$ it is $f'(x)=\frac{|x|}{x}=0 \iff x=0$, but since $0 \notin(-1,1) \setminus \{0\}$ there aren't internal stationary points.

The only internal point where $f$ is not differentiable is $x=0$, and it is $f(0)=1$.

It is $\partial([-1,1])=\{-1,1\}$, and it is $f(-1)=f(1)=2$; since $f(0) \leq f(-1)=f(1)$ it follows that $f$ has maximum $2$ for $x=1$ or $x=-1$ and $f$ has minimum $1$ for $x=0$.

Is this correct? I have a doubt when I evaluate $f'$: one of the hypothesis of Fermat's theorem on stationary points is that $f$ is defined in an open interval $(a,b)$, but in this case I have $(-1,1) \setminus \{0\}$ which is not an interval (if I'm not wrong, a union of interval in general is not an interval). So I'm not sure about my work in that point. My work is wrong and I can save it by considering the two cases $f_1(x)=1-x$ for $x \in (-1,0)$ and $f_2(x)=1+x$ for $x\in(0,1)$, in this way  $f_1$ and $f_2$ are defined on  intervals so all is fine and I just have to take the union of the results I obtain in the single intervals $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$? Or my work is correct as well? Thanks.

Comment: It is correct. You can also simplify by considering that $f$ is even and restrict your study to $[0,1]$, where $f(x)=1+x$ (paying special attention to $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated ?

We have $f(x) \ge 1$ for all $x$ and $f(0)=1.$

Furthermore: $f(x) \le 2 $ for all $x \in [-1,1]$ and $f( \pm 1)=2.$

Comment: Q: Why so complicated?  A: The point is to apply the general method.  Learning the general method lets you also solve other problems like this where the answer is not obvious.  As we see, the OP has questions about the general method.

Comment: @Fred: Thanks for your answer and for your alternative way to solve the problem; however, as GEdgar says, the question was about the general method and I just proposed an example.

Answer (score 1):

Note that writing

> $f'(x) = \dfrac{|x|}{x} = 0 \iff x = 0$

is not correct. ($\impliedby$ does not make sense.)

What you have done otherwise is fine.

---

However, this can be done in a much easier manner. First, noting that $|x| \ge 0$ gives $f(x) \ge 1$. On the other hand, $1$ is indeed attained since $f(0) = 1$. This finishes the proof.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; you're right, it should be $\implies$. My mistake was confusing the function $\text{sgn}(x)$ with the function $\frac{|x|}{x}$, which are not the same because $\frac{|x|}{x}$ is not defined for $x=0$. If I want to use it, I should define it $0$ for $x=0$. Thanks for your correction. Thanks for your altenrative manner as well.

Comment: That is correct. However, do note that the bigger problem is that $f'(x)$ does not make sense when $x = 0$. So, even if you write $f'(x) = \text{sgn}(x) = 0 \iff x = 0$, it will still not be correct!

Comment: Yes, $x=0$ is not in the domain of $f'$; so even if its numerator is $0$ if and only if $x=0$ this can't be a value that $x$ can assume. I have used the symbol $\iff$ because I meant that a fraction is zero if and only if its numerator is zero, but now that you pointed out this I see that the use of this symbol is incorrect in this context. Thanks!